# error requested source is not available after running jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

Which will take input username and password
ans pass it to validation.jsp

**login.jsp**

```
<center>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Login Here</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**validation.jsp**
It will validate the data from the database and return;

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    try{
        String username = request.getParameter("username");   
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tejas?" + "user=root&password=tejas");    
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select user,pass from login where user=tejas and pass=te65");
        pst.setString(1, username);
        pst.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();                        
        if(rs.next())           
           out.println("Valid login credentials");        
        else
           out.println("Invalid login credentials");            
   }
   catch(Exception e){       
       out.println("Something went wrong !! Please try again");       
   }      
%>`
```

This are both the codes saved under webapps folder
 webapps folder contains web-inf login.jsp validation.jsp

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1"
metadata-complete="true">
<display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
<description>
Welcome to Tomcat
</description>
</web-app>
```

do i need to add something to web.xml
please help...

Comment: jsp is for dispaly purposes not db access and business logic.  Move this code into a servlet

Comment: your submit button doesn't redirect to validate.jsp

Answer (score 2):

**First**
You `setString` without any `?` in your query, you have to use, so if you want something dynamique you have to use :

```
 pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select user,pass from login where user=? and pass=?");
 //------------------------------------------------------------------^----------^
 pst.setString(1, username);
 pst.setString(2, password);
```

If you want the username and password fix, then you don't need to use `.setString`.

Comment: ya did it but still the same error requested source is not available

Comment: @TejasZambre can you put `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch and show us your exact error?